# Jquery Ajax returns success but the returned data is false

Tags: jquery, joomla2.5

We are new to JQuery/Ajax and have taken the code from an example on the web.
We have the following code and it works fine when accessing one table but when we change it to access a different table it comes back as successful but the data returned returns false even though the data accessed is there.

This is the called program

```
$host = "db";
$user = "xxxxxxxxx";
$pass = "xxxxxxxxx";
$databaseName = "xxxxxxxxx";
$tableName = "**ocl_drivers**";

$id = $_GET['id'];
$con = mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass);
$dbs = mysql_select_db($databaseName, $con);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $tableName Where ID =".$id);      
$array = mysql_fetch_row($result);                                           
echo json_encode($array);
?>
```

This is the joomla article that does the call

```
  {source}

  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"         type="text/javascript"></script>

  <input type="text" id="userid" value="50">
  <input type="button" id="button" value="get user">
  <h2> Todays Job </h2>
  <div id="output"></div>

  <script id="source" language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

  $(document).ready(function() { 

    $("#button").click(function() { 

    $.ajax({ 

      url: '/reports/api1.php', //the script to call to get data 

      data: "id="+$('#userid').val(), 
      dataType: 'json', //data format 

      success: function(data) //on recieve of reply
      {
        var id = data[0]; //get id
        var vname = data[1]; //get name
        $('#output').html("<b>id: </b>"+id+"<b> name: </b>"+vname); //Set output element html
      }
    }); 
  }); 
}); 
</script>
```

{/source}

Everything works fine when we access the users table (ocl_users) but when we change it to access the drivers table it does not rerun the data even though the data does exit.

Any help would really be appreciated.

Thanks
Richard

Comment: Ajax will call success if it executed without an exception, the data it returns does not come into it

Comment: So are you sure your driver table as a field named 'ID' and corresponding to an userId value?

Answer (score 0):

I believe, this is a common problem with jquery if the data is in a tab.

I had a similar problem where I was loading data in one tab, and in the next tab I was loading a Google Map.

It didnt load the map properly cause it had to be re-initialized.

Can you show me the page?